# Conditional Validation in asp.net MVC4

Tags: jquery-validate, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to be able to kick off some validation functions based upon what controller a view is called from... I will set a variable in ViewState or something and that will help me to know what controller this view was called from.

In other words, I want the validation to be required if a certain variable is set...  Here is how I use to do in MVC2 when I just put Jquery into my code...

```
HospitalFinNumber: {
                    required: function (element) {
                        debugger;
                        return '@isFlagSet' != 'True'; 
                    },
                    minlength: 6,
                    remote: function () {
                        //debugger;
                        return {
                            url: '@Url.Action("ValidateHosFin", "EditEncounter")',
                            data: { hospitalFin: $('#HospitalFinNumber').val(), encflag: '@encflag' }
                        };
                    }
                }
```

You see what I am doing there.  This validation would only be required if a certain variable is set... In this case, the variable isFlagSet...  I would then set min Length and call a remote function to ensure that the value is unique.

I don't want to do this in all cases.

From all I have read so far, there is no clear way to accomplish this using unobrtusive ajax?  Am I wrong, is there a way you can do this?  If not, how can I just place regular old jquery validation into my code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC 3 uses jquery unobtrusive validation to perform client side validation. So you could either write a [custom `RequiredIf`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6495510/29407) validation attribute or use the one provided in [Mvc Foolproof Validation](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) and then:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [RequiredIf("IsFlagSet", true)]
    [Remote("ValidateHosFin", "EditEncounter")]
    [MinLength(6)]
    public string HospitalFinNumber { get; set; }

    public bool IsFlagSet { get; set; }

    public string EncFlag { get; set; }
}
```

Then all that's left is to include the `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` scripts or use the corresponding bundle in ASP.NET MVC 4 that includes them.

Comment: Hey Darin.  Been a while since I have heard from you.  But it sounds like that is the way to go.

Comment: I have to add here, that Foolproof has still no Entity Framework support! If you are wondering why you are getting a "Not Implemented Exception" on db.SaveChanges(); you might feel like me and need to realize that this is not coded yet... see also: http://foolproof.codeplex.com/workitem/18457

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov It's not working on MVC 4 bcos it didn't call RequiredIfValidator

Comment: Yes, as far as I tried foolproof seems to not working on MVC4? Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Another solution suggested by [Andy West](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171134/andy-west) on his [blog](http://andrewtwest.com/2011/01/10/conditional-validation-with-data-annotations-in-asp-net-mvc/) is to **Conditionally Remove Fields from the Model State in the Controller**:

When the form is posted, remove the fields from the model state so they’re not validated:

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    ModelState.Remove("CommenterName");
    ModelState.Remove("Email");
}
```

That worked for me.

Comment: Not bad.  It's a couple of years late, but Ill take it.

Comment: That's all well and good, but the Javascript validation still kicks in which keeps the form from posting and never reaches the controller.  In my situation, it was if the country in a registration form is "USA" then validate the Zip as a 5 or 5+4 format.  If it isn't USA, then ignore validation for that field. This seems like it would be common functionality with no good solution that can be found.  besides controller side validation with a slew of javascript that removes or adds back the validation data attributes, which is cludgy.