# MVC 4 - Is it possible to turn on/off parts of model validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model, data-annotations

I have a form in MVC 4 which has some optional parts. For example the form is used for inserting a new person record but there is also optional fields for relatives and claims. I hide and show these parts of the form with checkboxes and some jQuery. So these fields on the page exist but the div that it's inside visibility property is false.

**Dependant Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Models
{
    public class ModelDependant
    {
        public Guid DependantID { get; set; }
        public Guid PersonID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string RelationToDependant { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
         [Required]
        public string Surname { get; set; }
         [Required]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Borough { get; set; }
        public string PostCode { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string PrimaryLanguage { get; set; }
        public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Date of birth")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string Nationality { get; set; }
        public string Ethnicity { get; set; }
        public string Religion { get; set; }

        public bool boolSuccess { get; set; }
        public string strMessage { get; set; }
        public string strAction { get; set; }
        public bool boolDelete { get; set; }

    }
}
```

A list of these can be in this model

```
using Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Models
{
    public class modelClaimDatabase
    {
        public modelClaimDatabase()
        {
            modelPerson = new modelPerson();
            modelClaim = new modelClaim();
            LinkerStatusOfClaim = new List<LinkerStatusOfClaim>();
            modelClaimStatus = new List<modelClaimStatus>();
            modelPeopleGrid = new List<modelPeopleGrid>();
            ModelDependants = new List<ModelDependant>();
        }

        public modelPerson modelPerson { get; set; }
        public modelClaim modelClaim { get; set; }
        public List<modelClaimStatus> modelClaimStatus { get; set; }
        public List<LinkerStatusOfClaim> LinkerStatusOfClaim { get; set; }
        public List<modelPeopleGrid> modelPeopleGrid { get; set; }
        public List<ModelDependant> ModelDependants { get; set; }


        // Properties for controller
        public bool isValidModel { get; set; }


        public bool boolSuccess { get; set; }
        public string strMessage { get; set; }
        public string strAction { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Below is my view which is binded with modelClaimDatabase**

```
@model Models.modelClaimDatabase
<h4>
    @Html.Label("Edit details for: " + Model.modelPerson.Firstname + " " + Model.modelPerson.Surname)
</h4>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div id="divPerson" style="padding: 5px;">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.modelPerson.PersonID)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.modelPerson.Salutation)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.modelPerson.Salutation, new List<SelectListItem>
                     {
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Mr", Value = "Mr" }, 
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Mrs", Value = "Mrs" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Miss", Value = "Miss" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Ms", Value = "Ms" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Dr", Value = "Dr" }
                     })

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.modelPerson.Firstname)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.modelPerson.Firstname)
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.modelPerson.Firstname)

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.modelPerson.Surname)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.modelPerson.Surname)
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.modelPerson.Surname)

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.modelPerson.TelephoneNumber)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.modelPerson.TelephoneNumber)
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.modelPerson.TelephoneNumber)

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.modelPerson.AltTelephoneNumber)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.modelPerson.AltTelephoneNumber)

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.modelPerson.Address)
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.modelPerson.Address)
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.modelPerson.Address)

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.modelPerson.PostCode)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.modelPerson.PostCode)
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.modelPerson.PostCode)

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.modelPerson.PrimaryLanguage)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.modelPerson.PrimaryLanguage, new List<SelectListItem>
                     {
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Spanish", Value = "Spanish" }, 
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="English", Value = "English" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="French", Value = "French" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Italian", Value = "Italian" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Portugese", Value = "Portugese" }
                     })
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.modelPerson.PrimaryLanguage)

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.modelPerson.OtherLanguage)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.modelPerson.OtherLanguage, new List<SelectListItem>
                     {
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="English", Value = "Spanish" }, 
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Spanish", Value = "English" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="French", Value = "French" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Italian", Value = "Italian" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Portugese", Value = "Portugese" }
                     })

         @Html.LabelFor(m => m.modelPerson.DateOfBirth)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.modelPerson.DateOfBirth, new { @class = "datepicker" })
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.modelPerson.DateOfBirth)

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.modelPerson.Nationality)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.modelPerson.Nationality, new List<SelectListItem>
                     {
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="English", Value = "Spanish" }, 
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Spanish", Value = "English" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="French", Value = "French" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Italian", Value = "Italian" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Portugese", Value = "Portugese" }
                     })

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.modelPerson.OtherNationality)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.modelPerson.OtherNationality, new List<SelectListItem>
                     {
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="English", Value = "Spanish" }, 
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Spanish", Value = "English" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="French", Value = "French" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Italian", Value = "Italian" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Portugese", Value = "Portugese" }
                     })


        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.modelPerson.Ethnicity)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.modelPerson.Ethnicity, new List<SelectListItem>
                     {
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="White", Value = "White" }, 
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Black", Value = "Black" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Mixed-Race", Value = "Mixed-Race" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Indian", Value = "Indian" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Chinese", Value = "Chinese" }
                     })

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.modelPerson.Religion)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.modelPerson.Religion, new List<SelectListItem>
                     {
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Christian", Value = "Christian" }, 
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Muslim", Value = "Muslim" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Jewish", Value = "Jewish" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Hindu", Value = "Hindu" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Sikh", Value = "Sikh" }
                     })


        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.modelPerson.HasDisability)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.modelPerson.HasDisability, new { @id = "chkHasDisability" })

        <div id="divDisability" style="border-style: solid; border-width: thin; padding: 5px;">
            @Html.Label("Please provide more details")
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.modelPerson.Disability)
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.modelPerson.Disability)

        </div>

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.modelPerson.HasDependants)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.modelPerson.HasDependants, new { @id = "chkHasDependants" })



        <hr />
        <div id="divDependants" style="border-style: solid; border-width: thin; padding: 5px;">
            <div style="background-color: #C8C8C8">
                @Html.Label("Dependants data")
            </div>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Add dependant" name="btnSubmit" />

            <br />
            <hr />
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ModelDependants.Count; i++)
            {
                int status = i + 1;



                <table>
                    <tr>
                    <td>@Html.Label("Dependant: " + status.ToString()) </td>
                        <td>@Html.Label("Delete this dependant:")
                        </td>
                        <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ModelDependants[i].boolDelete)</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>



                <br />@*
                 <input type="submit" value="Remove Dependant @status.ToString()" name="btnSubmit" />*@

                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ModelDependants[i].PersonID)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ModelDependants[i].DependantID)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ModelDependants[i].RelationToDependant)
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ModelDependants[i].RelationToDependant)

                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ModelDependants[i].Firstname)
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ModelDependants[i].Firstname)

                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ModelDependants[i].Surname)
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ModelDependants[i].Surname)

                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ModelDependants[i].DateOfBirth)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ModelDependants[i].DateOfBirth, new { @class = "datepicker" })

                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ModelDependants[i].Address)
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ModelDependants[i].Address)

                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ModelDependants[i].Borough)
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ModelDependants[i].Borough)

                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ModelDependants[i].PostCode)
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ModelDependants[i].PostCode)

                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ModelDependants[i].Gender)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ModelDependants[i].Gender, new List<SelectListItem>
                     {
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Male", Value = "Male" }, 
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Female", Value = "Female" }
                     })

                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ModelDependants[i].PrimaryLanguage)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ModelDependants[i].PrimaryLanguage, new List<SelectListItem>
                     {
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Spanish", Value = "Spanish" }, 
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="English", Value = "English" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="French", Value = "French" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Italian", Value = "Italian" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Portugese", Value = "Portugese" }
                     })
                <br />

                <hr />
            }
            <br />


        </div>

    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Edit person record" name="btnSubmit" />
}

@* Date JS Logic *@
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            showStatus: true,
            showWeeks: true,
            currentText: 'Now',
            autoSize: true,
            gotoCurrent: true,
            showAnim: 'drop',
            highlightWeek: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
        $("#anim").change(function () {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker("option", "showAnim", $(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function hideGenericLbl() {
        $("#lblGenericMessage").css("color", "red");
        $("#lblGenericMessage").fadeOut(5000);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        hideGenericLbl();

        @if (Model.ModelDependants.Count > 0)
        {
             @:$("#chkHasDependants").prop('checked', true);
                }

        @if (Model.strMessage != null)
        {
            if (Model.isValidModel == false &&
            Model.strMessage.Contains("Must be at least one claim status if making a claim.") ||
            Model.strMessage.Contains("New claim status available") ||
            Model.strMessage.Contains("One claim status removed."))
            {
                @:$("#modelClaim_ClaimMade").prop('checked', true);
                        @:$("#modelPerson_HasDependants").prop('checked', true);
            }
        }

        $("#divClaimType").hide();
        $("#divClaimStatus").hide();
        $("#divDisability").hide();
        $("#divDependants").hide();

        // Claims
        if ($('#modelClaim_ClaimMade').is(':checked')) {
            $("#divClaimType").show();
            $("#divClaimStatus").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#divClaimType").hide();
            $("#divClaimStatus").hide();
        }
        // Disability
        if ($('#chkHasDisability').is(':checked')) {
            $("#divDisability").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#divDisability").hide();
        }

        // Dependants
        if ($('#chkHasDependants').is(':checked')) {
            $("#divDependants").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#divDependants").hide();
        }

    });
    // Claim made logic
    $("#modelClaim_ClaimMade").click(function () {
        if ($('#modelClaim_ClaimMade').is(':checked')) {
            $("#divClaimType").show();
            $("#divClaimStatus").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#divClaimType").hide();
            $("#divClaimStatus").hide();
        }
    });
    //Disability logic
    $("#chkHasDisability").click(function () {
        if ($('#chkHasDisability').is(':checked')) {
            $("#divDisability").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#divDisability").hide();
        }
    });

    //Dependant logic
    $("#chkHasDependants").click(function () {
        if ($('#chkHasDependants').is(':checked')) {
            $("#divDependants").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#divDependants").hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

In my screenshot, has dependants is using

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.modelPerson.HasDependants, new { @id = "chkHasDependants" })
```

I use this simple boolean to dictate if Entity framework creates a depandant.

Is there a way to turn off/on validators in my controller based on this boolean?

[image: Required fields]

**Finally, this is my controller with (IsModelState.Valid) condition**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string btnSubmit, FormCollection collection, modelClaimDatabase Model)
        {
            RepositoryClient RC = new RepositoryClient();
            switch (btnSubmit)
            {
                case "Add dependant":
                    #region AddDependant
                    // Get Claim types for VIEW
                    GetClaims(Model);
                    //Add new claim to list
                    Model.ModelDependants.Insert(Model.ModelDependants.Count, new ModelDependant());
                    // SET to false as Model is not ready for DB
                    Model.isValidModel = false;

                    // SET message for the user
                    Model.strMessage = "One dependant association added.";
                    return View("Index", Model);
                    #endregion
                case "Remove dependant":
                    #region RemoveDependant
                    // Can't remove IF only 1 
                    Model.isValidModel = false;
                    GetClaims(Model);
                    if (Model.ModelDependants.Count == 1)
                    {
                        Model.strMessage = "Must be at least one dependant if person has dependants.";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Model.ModelDependants.RemoveAt(Model.ModelDependants.Count - 1);
                        Model.strMessage = "One dependant association removed.";

                    }
                    return View("Index", Model);
                    #endregion
                case "Add claim status":
                    #region AddClaimStatus
                    // Get Claim types for VIEW
                    GetClaims(Model);
                    //Add new claim to list
                    Model.LinkerStatusOfClaim.Insert(Model.LinkerStatusOfClaim.Count, new LinkerStatusOfClaim());
                    // SET to false as Model is not ready for DB
                    Model.isValidModel = false;
                    // SET message for the user
                    Model.strMessage = "New claim status available";
                    return View("Index", Model);
                    #endregion
                case "Remove claim status":
                    #region RemoveClaimStatus
                    // Can't remove IF only 1 
                    Model.isValidModel = false;
                    GetClaims(Model);
                    if (Model.LinkerStatusOfClaim.Count == 1)
                    {
                        Model.strMessage = "Must be at least one claim status if making a claim.";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Model.LinkerStatusOfClaim.RemoveAt(Model.LinkerStatusOfClaim.Count - 1);
                        Model.strMessage = "One claim status removed.";

                    }
                    return View("Index", Model);
                    #endregion
                case "Save person record to database":
                    #region submit
                    GetClaims(Model);
                    Model.isValidModel = ModelState.IsValid;
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        // First create a new person record
                        RC.CreatePerson(Model);

                        // Only do other inserts if Person successfully created.
                        switch (Model.modelPerson.HasDependants && Model.modelPerson.boolSuccess)
                        {
                            case true:
                                RC.CreateDependant(Model);
                                break;
                            case false:
                                Model.ModelDependants.RemoveAt(0);
                                break;
                        }

                        switch (Model.modelClaim.ClaimMade && Model.modelPerson.boolSuccess)
                        {
                            case true:
                                RC.CreateClaim(Model);
                                break;
                            case false:
                                Model.LinkerStatusOfClaim.RemoveAt(0);
                                break;
                        }

                        // Do one final check before going to success screen
                        if (!Model.modelPerson.boolSuccess)
                        {
                            return View("Index", Model);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Model.strMessage = "Person data could not be inserted into the database. Missing key fields.";
                        return View("Index", Model);
                    }

                    // Use to persist data through redirect - Model data will be lost otherwise
                    TempData["Model"] = Model;
                    return RedirectToAction("Success");

            }
            return View();
                    #endregion
        }
```

**Summary**

Turn off parts of model validation based on model property. Is it possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843282/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc4

Answer (score 0):

One option is [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) that Matt have referenced, it provide simple conditional validation on both client and server side.

If you want to only disable the validation on client side or for whatever reason you don't want to use foolproof plugin, there's also a dirty javascript way:

```
if(condition){
    $("#Property1").rules("remove");  //This will remove validation for the specific input
    //...
}
```

In your case it might also we something like this:

```
$("#Property1").change(function(){
    $("#Property2").rules("remove");
    //...
});
```

Make sure these javascript code comes AFTER your jquery.validation.js

Let me know if it helps.