# Entity validation require one of many fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have an Entity that has two flags, each having a value. For illustrative purposes, we'll use the below code:

```
public partial class ExampleEntity
{
    public bool OptionA { get; set; }
    public int OptionAValue { get;set; }
    public bool OptionB { get; set; }
    public int OptionBValue { get;set; }
}
```

On the Webform used, If neither Option is checked, a flag needs to be thrown.
If an option is checked, then only the corresponding value should need to be required/populated/evaluated.

Now I know I can use the [Required] tag and other associated tags ([Range(1,100)]), but what I'm not sure of is how to group them (if possible) or where to add the logic to determine whether or not the values for A or B are required based on their entered values.

Comment: look at foolproof,  see the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843282/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc4

Comment: On the EF front you could either create a custom validation attribute or implement the IValidatableObject interface to perform custom logic - see some examples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Pawel said, you could implement the IValidatableObject interface (example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959#IValidatableObject)

For your specific case you could do:

```
public partial class ExampleEntity : IValidatableObject
{
    public bool OptionA { get; set; }
    public int OptionAValue { get;set; }
    public bool OptionB { get; set; }
    public int OptionBValue { get;set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (OptionA)
        {
            var aIsValid = PerformAValidation();
            if (!aIsValid)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("A was not valid", new[] {"OptionAValue", OptionAValue});
            }
        }

        if (OptionB)
        {
            var bIsValid = PerformBValidation();
            if (!bIsValid)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("B was not valid", new[] {"OptionBValue", OptionBValue});
            }
        }
    }

    private bool PerformAValidation()
    {
        if (OptionAValue < 100)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private bool PerformBValidation()
    {
        if (OptionBValue > 100)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

With these validation rules, OptionAValue would need to be less than 100 and OptionBValue would need to be greater than 100.

Comment: Thanks for the response all!
I'm assuming that PerformBValidation() is another class not shown above that I would use to check the contents of OptionBValue. If that's the case, then no need to confirm. 
 
Thanks again everyone!

Comment: PerformBValidaiton would just be a private method within your ExampleEntity class. I'll add a silly example.