# Custom validations for checkboxes and dropdowns

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I am using DataAnnotations for validations on one of my form. Validations for string type is okay. It works with required and error message. But I am having problem while validating checkboxes. I have certain kind of norms/Rules like.

I am having a set of checkboxes that contains 4 checkboxes.I want to validate it so that atleast one checkbox should be selected and that is must.
But in the case of gender, Gender should be marked but only one should be checked at a time.
 How can I achieve this in Mvc.

I am finding one more field difficult to validate and that is Dropdownlist which is binded with ViewBag. How can one validate the drop down using dataAnnotations if Dropdown is binded with Viewbag. I am using A hidden field to post the value of Dropdownlist.Below is my code::

I am really digging it hard to find the solution.

```
View Page
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@model MvcValidation.Models.Model
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>


<style type="text/css">
    #DataContent
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 1000px;
    }

    .Contentdiv
    {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .HeadingDiv
    {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 2%;
    }

    .CommonDiv
    {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .LeftDiv
    {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }
</style>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Register", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "updateSuccess" }))
{

    <div id="DataContent">
        <div class="Contentdiv">
            <div class="HeadingDiv">Register here</div>
            <div class="CommonDiv">
                <div class="LeftDiv">
                    Name
                </div>
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ddlValue)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Gender_Check)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Mood_Check)
                <div class="LeftDiv">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="CommonDiv">
                <div class="LeftDiv">
                    Email
                </div>
                <div class="LeftDiv">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="CommonDiv">
                <div class="LeftDiv">
                    Father Name
                </div>
                <div class="LeftDiv">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FatherName)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FatherName)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="CommonDiv">
                <div class="LeftDiv">
                    Mother Name
                </div>
                <div class="LeftDiv">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MotherName)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MotherName)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="CommonDiv">
                <div class="LeftDiv">
                    Country
                </div>
                <div class="LeftDiv">
                    @Html.DropDownList("myCountriesDDL", (SelectList)ViewBag.Countries, "Select")
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="CommonDiv">
                <div class="LeftDiv">
                    Gender
                </div>
                <div class="LeftDiv">
                    Male @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Male)
                    Female @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Female)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="CommonDiv">
                <div class="LeftDiv">
                    Mood
                </div>
                <div class="LeftDiv">
                    None @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.None)
                    Mild @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Mild)
                    Moderate @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Moderate)
                    Severe @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Severe)
                    Flexible @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Flexible)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Mood_Check)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="CommonDiv">
                <div class="LeftDiv">
                </div>
                <div class="LeftDiv">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="AssignValues();" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}


<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateSuccess(Json) {
        alert(Json.Msg);
    }
    function AssignValues() {
    var country = $("#myCountriesDDL").val();
    $("#ddlValue").val(country);

    if ($("#None").checked == true || $("#Mild").checked == true || $("#Moderate").checked == true
        || $("#Severe").checked == true || $("#Flexible").checked == true) {
        $("#Mood_Check").val("Checked");
    }
}
</script>


Model//
public class Model
    {
        public bool None { get; set; }
        public bool Mild { get; set; }
        public bool Severe { get; set; }
        public bool Moderate { get; set; }
        public bool Flexible { get; set; }
        public bool Male { get; set; }
        public bool Female { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required")]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Father name is required")]
        public string FatherName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Mother name is required")]
        public string MotherName { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string ddlValue { get; set; }
       [Required(ErrorMessage = "Mood is required")]
        public string Mood_Check { get; set; }
       [Required(ErrorMessage = "Gender is required")]
       public string Gender_Check { get; set; }
    }


Controller

 public ActionResult Register(Model ObjModel)
        {
            return Json(new { Msg = "Hello" });
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843282/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc4

Comment: As a start, i think you should change checkboxes for Gender with radio buttons (so you can only select one of them). Also, you can create a hidden field (which will be required), and set it's value only after you checked one of the checkboxes. If you try to submit the form without checking one of the checkboxes, the hidden field will be empty, which will trigger a `required` error

Comment: Hidden field concept is not working. Please check above code I have implemented that and Radiobutton can'nt be applied as Checkboxes are compulsory. Please give your valuable suggestion

Comment: If you are using `jquery unobtrusive validation`, by default, hidden inputs are not validated. To fix this, add `$.validator.defaults.ignore = [];` on `$(document).ready()`. Radio buttons are made for `one option choice`, you can see them in many registration forms.

Comment: I have used the above code given by you like this because it does not works in document.ready
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: [] });
and yes it worked but after filling the information also, I am not able to post the form.. Form is not posting due to above line.