# MVC hiding/showing a partial view with a form on another form, save issue

Tags: jquery, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have a form in a view that has a partial view hidden when the application launches because it is only shown when a user clicks a certain link. I am using RenderAction within the hidden div, and maybe that is the wrong way to go about this. The partial view is another form (from another model) that they must submit before submitting the main form (only if they click the link). When the user clicks the Assign link, the main save button disappears and the partial view is unhidden with the new save button. My issue is that the Submit button on my main page is not working when I do not care about the partial view, but rather the button on my partial view is acting as the main save button and the main save button does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //hide the partial view
        $('#assignment').hide();

       //hide the main save button and show the partial view
       $('.lauch-quick-assign').on('click', function (event) {
           $('#main-save-edit').hide();
           $('#assignment').show();
       });

    });
```

My View:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        //main form area    

       <a href="#" class="lauch-quick-assign">Assign</a>

       <div id="assignment"> //this partial views form is acting as the main save button, but is not saving itself
           @{Html.RenderAction("Assign", "Assignment", new { ID = Model.InfoId});}
       </div>

       <p>  //not working
          <input type="submit" value="Save" id="main-save-edit"/>
       </p>


    }
```

Comment: if you remove the partial from the page, does the submit button work?

Comment: is it form element within a form element? If yes, its not allowed in HTML.

Comment: @MattBodily, yes it worked once removed.@LostInComputer, I guess that is my answer and must think of a different approach.

Comment: In this situation I would recommend sending all of the data on that one button call every time and using conditional validation to only validation the partial if that check is true,  see here for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843282/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc4

Comment: so it seems like I can put the Required attribute on a hidden property and the validation works when it is visible. And when it is hidden it allows the user to submit the form (exactly what I want). Do you know why that happens? The RequiredIf class with jQuery seems over my head since I need it to fire when a drop down list changes from the original value and all the examples I saw used discrete values or another flag property to determine if something changes, and to be honest I would not know how to implement that flag to change without a post back to the server.

Answer (score 1):

See Matt's answer in the comments section under my question. I moved everything to one button call

> In this situation I would recommend sending all of the data on that one button call every time and using conditional validation to only validation the partial if that check is true, see here for more info stackoverflow.com/questions/12843282/… –  Matt Bodily Feb 3 at 16:25