# MVC4 razor with jQuery for validation

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I typed up so code to help with validation for my view in C# MVC 4, and it works:

**jQuery Code:**

```
 $("#CountryDDL").change(function () {
 if ($("#CountryDDL").val() == 'CA' || $("#CountryDDL").val() == 'US') {

    $("#submitButton").attr("onclick", "return false;");
 }
 else if ($("#CountryDDL").val() != 'CA' || $("#CountryDDL").val() != 'US') {
     $("#submitButton").removeAttr("onclick");
 }
});
 $("#ProvinceDDL, #StateDDL").change(function () {

 if ($("#ProvinceDDL").val() != 'NULL' || $("#StateDDL").val() != 'NULL') {
    $("#submitButton").removeAttr("onclick");

 }
 else if ($("#ProvinceDDL").val() == 'NULL' || $("#StateDDL").val() == 'NULL') {
     $("#submitButton").attr("onclick", "return false;");
 }
 });
```

**What The jQuery Does**:

This jQuery is to help validate two fields ultimately (three technically). If The user selects Canada or United States they are forced to select a province or state otherwise they cannot submit.

**The Problem:**

However, since I have onclick to return false it doesn't let the validation for the other fields to go through on this page.

Is there a way to let C# run the validation for the other fields and run my jQuery validation at the same time on click?

Comment: How about using `flag`? At first, `flag = true;`. For each validation step, if it doesn't pass, assign `flag = false;`. Finally, you can set the return value of submit button based on `flag` value.

Answer (score 0):

for conditional validation like you mention I use foolproof.  see here [Conditional Validation in asp.net MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843282/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc4)

then in jquery you can do

```
$('.btnSubmit').on('click', function(e){
    if($('form').valid()){
    }else{
        e.preventDefault();
        var $validate = $('form').validate();
    }
});
```

so it will fire the validation and if the form isn't valid then prevent default will stop the submit from happening.  Hopefully this helps

Answer (score 0):

A word of warning you are implementing only client side validation, i hope you have corresponding server side validation.

The correct approach to your problem is to impalement MVC validators for both server and client side so you can annotate your model. Here is an example, adding validators to your model will correctly tie in with the unobtrusive MVC validation and you will not have write javascript with hard coded values. There are many validators to help you out such as [Required] and google for others.

Example code is taken from and another link to help you out.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-helpers,-forms-and-validation

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model

```
public class Album
     {  
          [Required(ErrorMessage = "An Album Title is required")]
          [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
          [StringLength(160, MinimumLength = 2)]
          public string Title { get; set; }

          [Required(ErrorMessage = "Price is required")]
          [Range(0.01, 100.00, ErrorMessage = "Price must be between 0.01 and 100.00")]
          [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
          public decimal Price { get; set; }

          [DisplayName("Album Art URL")]
          [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
          [StringLength(1024)]
          public string AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }
     }
```