# Best way to implement a Require validation if another field is not null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ivalidatableobject

I have the following two fields inside my view:-

```
<div>

<span class="f">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.Firewall.ConsoleServerID)</span>

@Html.DropDownListFor(model =>model.Firewall.ConsoleServerID, ((IEnumerable<IT.Models.ITConsoleServer>)ViewBag.Servers).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.Technology.Tag), 
Value = option.ConsoleServerID.ToString(),
Selected = (Model != null) && (Model.Firewall.ITConsoleServer != null) && (option.ConsoleServerID == Model.Firewall.ConsoleServerID)
}), "Choose...")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.Firewall.ConsoleServerID)

</div>

<div >
<span class="f">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.Firewall.ConsoleServerPort)</span> 

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Firewall.ConsoleServerPort) 
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Firewall.ConsoleServerPort) |
```

The rule I want to implement is that both fields are NullAble, but if the user selects a ConsoleServerID , then he needs to add  a Port . and if the user leave the ConsoleServerID null then he should not enter a Port number.
So what is the best way to implement this scenario , so that I have both client side and server side validation ?
Thanks

**Edit**
After installing the foolproof i am facing the following problems :-

1. no client side validation is being implemented, and the validation is being implemented when checking if the model state is valid inside my controller class
2. if the [RequiredIfNotEmpty] is false then the suer will recive the following message:- Console Server Port is required due to ConsoleServerID not being empty .so why ConsoleServerID will be displayed instead of the field name which is Console Server Tag.
3. if the user tried to submit the form where the ConsoleServerID is null then i will recevie the following exception :-

> System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbUnexpectedValidationException was
>   unhandled by user code   HResult=-2146233087   Message=An unexpected
>   exception was thrown during validation of 'Console Server Port' when
>   invoking Foolproof.RequiredIfNotEmptyAttribute.IsValid. See the inner
>   exception for details.   Source=EntityFramework   StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.ValidationAttributeValidator.Validate(EntityValidationContext
>   entityValidationContext, InternalMemberEntry property)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.PropertyValidator.Validate(EntityValidationContext
>   entityValidationContext, InternalMemberEntry property)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.EntityValidator.ValidateProperties(EntityValidationContext
>   entityValidationContext, InternalPropertyEntry parentProperty, List`1
>   validationErrors)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.TypeValidator.Validate(EntityValidationContext
>   entityValidationContext, InternalPropertyEntry property)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.EntityValidator.Validate(EntityValidationContext
>   entityValidationContext)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.GetValidationResult(IDictionary`2
>   items)
>          at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.ValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary`2 items)
>          at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.GetValidationErrors()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
>          at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
>          at TMS.Models.Repository.Save() in c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\New folder
>   (19)\TMS\TMS\TMS\Models\Repository.cs:line 4614
>          at TMS.Controllers.FirewallController.Edit(FirewallJoin fj, FormCollection formValues) in c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\New
>   folder (19)\TMS\TMS\TMS\Controllers\FirewallController.cs:line 869
>          at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult
>   _)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.b__33()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49()
>   InnerException: System.NotImplementedException
>          HResult=-2147467263
>          Message=The method or operation is not implemented.
>          Source=MVC Foolproof Validation
>          StackTrace:
>               at Foolproof.ModelAwareValidationAttribute.IsValid(Object value)
>               at System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.IsValid(Object
>   value, ValidationContext validationContext)
>               at System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.GetValidationResult(Object
>   value, ValidationContext validationContext)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.ValidationAttributeValidator.Validate(EntityValidationContext
>   entityValidationContext, InternalMemberEntry property)
>          InnerException:

Comment: I like foolproof http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843282/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc4

Comment: but will the foolproof also implement a server-side validation ?, so if a hacker by pass the client side validation, the fooproof should check the validation on the server ?

Comment: yes it will.  just do a if(ModelState.IsValid) on the controller and it will return false if your condition isn't met

Comment: i have installed the foolproof , and i add the following [RequiredIfNotEmpty("ConsoleServerID")] on the ConsoleServerPort, but i have noted that no client side validation will be done, all the validation will be done inside the controller ,, can you adivce

Comment: also if the ConsoleServerId is null , then an exception will be raised ..

Comment: you can add a display name attribute to the property on your model which should change your validation message to the name you are wanting.  Hopefully the form.valid will fix the other issues once we can get that working

Comment: i already define a Display Name for the property, but seems that the foolproof did not recognize it ..

Answer (score 1):

We do a lot of ajax calls.  How I trigger the client side validation is

```
$('#btnClick').on('click', function(){
     if ($('form').valid()) {
         $.ajax({
         //call here
         });
     }
});
```

the form.valid triggers the validation on the form

Comment: but i need a more general approach which i can re-use all over the related views. the FoolProof is good but i am facing problem in using it..

Comment: it doesn't have to be an ajax call in the middle.  Just set it up to trigger off of a button click or some other selector and run the form.valid.  Make sure you have a form tag around the content you want validated

Comment: can you chekc my Edit please

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be to put that logic in your model

In your ViewModel, create a bool propery like this:

```
public bool IsAddingPortRequired
{
   get
   {
       return ConsoleServerID != null;
   }
}
```

Then, use your `RequiredIf` attribute like this:

```
[RequiredIf("IsAddingPortRequired", true, ErrorMessage = "You must add a port Number")]
```

Comment: so why i can not use the foolproof instead? and where i need to create the ISAddingPortRequired ? inside the model class itself ?

Comment: huh? `RequiredIf` **is** foolproof, as the builtin does not have this. yes put it right where you have `ConsoleServerID`

Comment: aha ok sorry for that, but why i can not use [RequiredIfNotEmpty] then ?

Comment: that im not sure (never tried it), maybe null and empty are not the same thing?

Comment: @johnG did you get a chance to try it? it should solve your issue