# How to validate a ViewModel models separated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I would like to use the ModelState.IsValid in a ViewModel with multiple models inside.

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public TestViewModel()
    {
        UserModel = new UserDTO();
        PaymentModel = new PaymentDTO();
        ResultModel = new ResultDTO();
        NewUserModel = new NewUserDTO();
    }

    public UserDTO UserModel  { get; set; }
    public NewUserDTO NewUserModel  { get; set; }
    public PaymentDTO PaymentModel { get; set; }
    public ResultDTO ResultModel { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my Action:

```
public ActionResult TestAction(TestViewModel model)
{
     ModelState.IsValid //Just for UserDTO in some condition or just the NewUserDTO in other condition
}
```

In my `Payment.cshtml` view strongly typed with `TestViewModel` , if its a new user i show the `_Register.cshtml` partial view strongly typed with the `NewUserDTO` model, and if the user is already registered i render the `_User.cshtml` partial view strongly typed with the `UserDTO` model. So, when the form is submited with a new user, i have to disregard the `UserModel`  validation.

Is it possible to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843282/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc4

Comment: derive fromIValidateableObject and have some flags inside the TestViewModel to turn on/off the validations