# Custom validation RequiredIf in MVC is not triggered

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, data-annotations, customvalidator

**Problem Statement:**

I'm using custom validation attribute `RequiredIf` to validate some fields in my `MVC-Razor` application. Everything was working fine, but recently we noticed, application was taking too much time to respond after spending some time with the application.

When contacted Microsoft support team, they suggested a change to the `RequiredIf`, as the current one is making the application to respond slowly. So we modified the old `RequiredIf` with the new one, but the current `RequiredIf` is not triggering the model data annotations which were triggering earlier.

What's wrong in the new `RequiredIf` attribute.

*Any suggestion/answer would be highly appreciated.??*

**Old RequiredIf Code:**

Codeproject link for more info: [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/234096/Multiple-Custom-DataAnnotations-on-Same-Field-With)

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
    {
        private readonly string defaultErrorMessageFormatString = "The {0} is required";
        public List<string> DependentProperties { get; private set; }
        public List<string> DependentValues { get; private set; }
        public string Props { get; private set; }
        public string Vals { get; private set; }
        public string RequiredFieldValue { get; private set; }

        //To avoid multiple rules with same name
        public static Dictionary<string, int> CountPerField;
        //Required if you want to use this attribute multiple times
        private readonly object typeId = new object();
        public override object TypeId
        {
            get { return typeId; }
        }

        public RequiredIfAttribute(string dependentProperties,
               string dependentValues = "", string requiredValue = "val")
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dependentProperties))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("dependentProperties");
            }
            string[] props = dependentProperties.Trim().Split(',');
            if (props != null && props.Length == 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Prameter Invalid:DependentProperties");
            }

            if (props.Contains("") || props.Contains(null))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Prameter Invalid:DependentProperties," +
                          "One of the Property Name is Empty");
            }

            string[] vals = null;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dependentValues))
                vals = dependentValues.Trim().Split(',');

            if (vals != null && vals.Length != props.Length)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Different Number " +
                      "Of DependentProperties And DependentValues");
            }

            DependentProperties = new List<string>();
            DependentProperties.AddRange(props);
            Props = dependentProperties.Trim();
            if (vals != null)
            {
                DependentValues = new List<string>();
                DependentValues.AddRange(vals);
                Vals = dependentValues.Trim();
            }

            if (requiredValue == "val")
                RequiredFieldValue = "val";
            else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(requiredValue))
            {
                RequiredFieldValue = string.Empty;
                defaultErrorMessageFormatString = "The {0} should not be given";
            }
            else
            {
                RequiredFieldValue = requiredValue;
                defaultErrorMessageFormatString =
                        "The {0} should be:" + RequiredFieldValue;
            }

            if (props.Length == 1)
            {
                if (vals != null)
                {
                    ErrorMessage = defaultErrorMessageFormatString +
                                   @", When " + props[0] + @" is ";
                    if (vals[0] == "val")
                        ErrorMessage += @" given";
                    else if (vals[0] == "")
                        ErrorMessage += @" not given";
                    else
                        ErrorMessage += vals[0];
                }
                else
                    ErrorMessage = defaultErrorMessageFormatString +
                                   @", When " + props[0] + @" is given";
            }
            else
            {
                if (vals != null)
                {
                    ErrorMessage = defaultErrorMessageFormatString +
                                   @", When " + dependentProperties + @" are: ";
                    foreach (string val in vals)
                    {
                        if (val == "val")
                            ErrorMessage += @"AnyValue,";
                        else if (val == "")
                            ErrorMessage += @"Empty,";
                        else
                            ErrorMessage += val + @",";
                    }
                    ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage.Remove(ErrorMessage.Length - 1);
                }
                else
                    ErrorMessage = defaultErrorMessageFormatString + @", When " +
                                   dependentProperties + @" are given";
            }
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value,
                           ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            //Validate Dependent Property Values First
            for (int i = 0; i < DependentProperties.Count; i++)
            {
                var contextProp =
                  validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().
                  GetProperty(DependentProperties[i]);
                var contextPropVal = Convert.ToString(contextProp.GetValue(
                                             validationContext.ObjectInstance, null));

                var requiredPropVal = "val";
                if (DependentValues != null)
                    requiredPropVal = DependentValues[i];

                if (requiredPropVal ==
                       "val" && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contextPropVal))
                    return ValidationResult.Success;
                else if (requiredPropVal == string.Empty &&
                            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contextPropVal))
                    return ValidationResult.Success;
                else if (requiredPropVal != string.Empty && requiredPropVal !=
                            "val" && requiredPropVal != contextPropVal)
                    return ValidationResult.Success;
            }

            string fieldVal = (value != null ? value.ToString() : string.Empty);

            if (RequiredFieldValue == "val" && fieldVal.Length == 0)
                return new ValidationResult(string.Format(
                           ErrorMessageString, validationContext.DisplayName));
            else if (RequiredFieldValue == string.Empty && fieldVal.Length != 0)
                return new ValidationResult(string.Format(
                           ErrorMessageString, validationContext.DisplayName));
            else if (RequiredFieldValue != string.Empty && RequiredFieldValue
                     != "val" && RequiredFieldValue != fieldVal)
                return new ValidationResult(string.Format(ErrorMessageString,
                                            validationContext.DisplayName));

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(
               ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        {
            int count = 0;
            string key = metadata.ContainerType.FullName + "." + metadata.GetDisplayName();

            if (CountPerField == null)
                CountPerField = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            if (CountPerField.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                count = ++CountPerField[key];
            }
            else
                CountPerField.Add(key, count);

            yield return new RequiredIfValidationRule(string.Format(ErrorMessageString,
                  metadata.GetDisplayName()), RequiredFieldValue, Props, Vals, count);
        }
    }


    public class RequiredIfValidationRule : ModelClientValidationRule
    {
        public RequiredIfValidationRule(string errorMessage, string reqVal,
               string otherProperties, string otherValues, int count)
        {
            int i = 0;

            while (count > 26)
            {
                count -= 26;
                i++;
            }

            var tmp = count == 0 ? "" : Char.ConvertFromUtf32(96 + count);
            while (i > 0)
            {
                tmp += tmp;
                i--;
            }

            ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
            ValidationType = "requiredif" + tmp;
            ValidationParameters.Add("reqval", reqVal);
            ValidationParameters.Add("others", otherProperties);
            ValidationParameters.Add("values", otherValues);
        }
    }
```

**New RequiredIf Code:**

Stackoverflow link for more info : [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495510/mvc-2-vs-mvc-3-custom-validation-attributes-using-dataannotationsmodelvalidatorp)

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private String PropertyName { get; set; }
    private Object DesiredValue { get; set; }
    private readonly RequiredAttribute _innerAttribute;

    public RequiredIfAttribute(String propertyName, Object desiredvalue)
    {
        PropertyName = propertyName;
        DesiredValue = desiredvalue;
        _innerAttribute = new RequiredAttribute();
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
    {
        if (context.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName) != null)
        {
            var dependentValue =
                context.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(context.ObjectInstance, null);

            if (dependentValue != null && dependentValue.ToString() == DesiredValue.ToString())
            {
                if (!_innerAttribute.IsValid(value))
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(context.DisplayName), new[] { context.MemberName });
                }
            }
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = ErrorMessageString,
            ValidationType = "requiredif",
        };
        // ReSharper disable once PossibleNullReferenceException
        rule.ValidationParameters["dependentproperty"] = (context as ViewContext).ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(PropertyName);
        rule.ValidationParameters["desiredvalue"] = DesiredValue is bool ? DesiredValue.ToString().ToLower() : DesiredValue;

        yield return rule;
    }


}
```

Comment: Is breakpoint hitting while debugging?

Comment: Another point, you should be doing `dependentValue.Equals(DesiredValue)` instead of `dependentValue.ToString() == DesiredValue.ToString()`. What type of validation is not working? Client-Side or Server-Side or Both?

Comment: Breakpoint is hitting while debugging.Both server side and client side validations not working with respect to RequiredIf. Whereas other Required validations are triggering.